# How to use calcRoute()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, directions

Anybody knows how to use calcRoute() function if there are multiple points in google map?

Currently, I have web application(asp.net) that can search city and store it in a listbox. At this point, I want to connect  all the points that I have stored in listBox. Based on the tutorial in [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints), I have to use function calcRoute(). Therefore, in javascript . I intiliaze  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

```
 function initialize() {


        var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433, 151.1956316);

        //route
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: pyrmont,
            zoom: 15

        });

        //city autocomplete 
        var input = document.getElementById('tbCity');
        var options = {
            types: ['(cities)']
        };

        //create markerCity objects
        var defaultCityMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map
        });


        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry) {
                return;
            }

            // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
                map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
                map.setZoom(15);
            }
            //defaultCityMarker.setIcon(yellowMarker);
            defaultCityMarker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
                url: place.icon,
                size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
            }));
            defaultCityMarker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            defaultCityMarker.setVisible(true);
        });

        placesList = document.getElementById('POIcontainer');

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var POIinput = (document.getElementById('tbSearch'));
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((POIinput));

        var searchButton = document.getElementById('btnSearch');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(searchButton, 'click', function () {
            var poiKeyword = document.getElementById('tbSearch').value;
            getListOfPOI(poiKeyword);
        });


    }
```

I have declared the calcRoute:

```
 function calcRoute() {

        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var waypts = [];
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var waypoints = []; // init an empty waypoints array
        //check list from listbox(?)

        for (var i = 0; i < ListBox2.length; i++) {
            start.push({
                location: ListBox2[0].value,
                stopover: true
            });
            waypts.push({
                location: ListBox2[i].value,
                stopover: true
            });

            end.push({
                location: ListBox2[ListBox2.length-1].value,
                stopover: true
            });
        }

        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                var route = response.routes[0];
            }
        });
    }
```

In this function I took the points (which is the item of listBox2) and initialize the start,waypoint and end in for statement. Unfortunately, it seems it doesn;t work. Anybody knows how to use calcroute?Thanks

Comment: Where is `calcRoute()` called?

Comment: I have button to generate the route, inside that I have use:  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "script", "<script type ='text/javascript'> calcRoute(); </script>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that `DirectionRenderer` for route is created

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

but map is not specified on which directions will be rendered:

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

In `createRoute()` start and end points are created:

```
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var waypts = [];
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
```

and then used as array and filled up as waypoints in a loop:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < ListBox2.length; i++) {
        start.push({
            location: ListBox2[0].value,
            stopover: true
        });
        waypts.push({
            location: ListBox2[i].value,
            stopover: true
        });

        end.push({
            location: ListBox2[ListBox2.length-1].value,
            stopover: true
        });
    }
```

If ListBox2 has 10 elements, `start` and `end` will have 10 elements at the end. So, it is not clear what is the source for those two points.

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/repiw/1/edit). `start` and `end` are hardcoded, waypoints are filled up from faked ListBox2 (0 and last index are skipped).